# Groovy File Name and Class Name different

Tags: grails, groovy

I am developing application using grails which uses groovy.I changed one of the domain class name say class A to class B.However this does not change the file name unlike the case with Java.Why is it so.My guess would be the A.groovy file is treated as groovy script and class name is a Java class?Please clarify..thanks

Comment: Which editor/IDE are you using? I know for NetBeans 7.4, the Groovy/Grails plugin has this problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rename a class, you need to need to rename the source file in which that class is defined.  If you are using an IDE's refactoring support, the IDE should do that for you.  Regardless, the file  name should be changed either by you or by your tools.

Comment: I am using intellij .When I change the class name inside the file,the groovy file name does not change.I am using latest release.

Comment: May because I manually changed the class name.I should have used shift + F6 to rename

Comment: Right. If you just changed the name of the class inside the source file, I don't think your IDE is going to react to that and rename the file.  Glad you got it straight.